# Do I have to pull the Docker RStudio image for every Docker container I want to create?

Tags: docker, rstudio

I'm following a tutorial on the creation and use of Docker containers in which, from the PowerShell/wsl command line, I first run:

```
# pull the image 
docker pull rocker/rstudio:4.0.5
```

My question is whether I have to pull a new instance of rocker/rstudio each time I want to create a new Docker container. It takes quite a while to download. Good time to walk the dog, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have figured this out, though please correct me if I'm wrong. In short, I do not need to pull RStudio each time I wish to create a Docker (or, rather, Rocker) container. From the "Images" window in Docker Desktop, I simply click on the "Run" command opposite "rocker/rstudio", and a new Rocker container is created.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).